# RegEx invalid quantifier

Tags: javascript, regex, match

```
var pattern = /(?<=\?)(.*?)(?=\=)/;
```

is throwing an "invalid quantifier" error.

I've tried:

```
var regexp = new RegExp("(?<=\?)(.*?)(?=\=)");
```

to no avail either. I've tried to escape the = signs and backslashes. I'm at a loss.

How can I fix this?

Comment: JavaScript does not support look-behinds.

Comment: I found a workaround. Apparently, when I hash the urlObj and apply the pattern that matches the "?" + string + "="... it returns an array... so it's messy but it works perfectly.

`var pattern = /(\?)(.*?)(\=)/;
 var urlType = urlObj.hash.match(pattern)[2];`

Comment: If you just wanted that, `/\?(.*?)=/.exec(urlObj.hash)[1]` would also work.

Answer (score 2):

As was said, JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds. You might find useful workarounds here: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript

Answer (score 0):

It seemed, that javascript Regexp doesn't support `(?<...)`

> Lookbehind is not supported at all.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

If you add : after the ?'s it should work.

```
var pattern = /(?:<=\?)(.*?)(?:=\=)/;
```

Comment: `?:` dereferences a group. The OP wants to use look-behinds, which he know from other RegEx implementations.

Answer (score 0):

why do you need look-behind? you are trying to match `?data=` type patterns right?  Don't just *look* for the `?`, eat it. :)

```
var data = "halsfdkjad;slfkjasdfj?data=uhtooiuhiouh?oiurhoiuhhhjkjj=9";
var myregexp = /\?(.*?)(?=\=)/g; 
var match = myregexp.exec(data);
var result = "Matches found:\n";
while (match != null) {
    result += "match:" + RegExp.$1 + '\n';
    match = myregexp.exec(data);
}
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. Apparently, when I hash the urlObj and apply the pattern that matches the "?" + string + "="... it returns an array... it's messy but it works perfectly.

```
var pattern = /(\?)(.*?)(\=)/; 
var urlType = urlObj.hash.match(pattern)[2];
```